# colors of bars in facet chart ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am making a bar chart with ggplot and using facet for showing the details.
I am using the following code.

```
g1 <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x=PF.Score))+
  geom_bar(color="Black", fill="skyblue")+
  geom_text(stat="count", aes(label=..count..), size =4, vjust=-0.3)+
  ylab("% of Suppliers")+
  xlab("Score of Suppliers")+
  ggtitle("Score distribution of suppliers")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.ticks.y= element_blank(),axis.text.y = element_blank())

  g2 <- g1+facet_wrap(~GROUP)
  g1+g2
```

and I am getting the following output

[Result Ouptput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH5Sb.jpg)

However i require each bar with different color,
e.g bar of "2" to be of "red", "3" to be of "blue" & so on & same colors in the facet Graph also.
but i am not able to get such colors in the bar-chart.
Also the colors will be used as legends.

Any Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: `geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(PF.Score)), color="Black")`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas..Thanks it solved the purpose..but can i choose colors of my choice as the different colors are coming as default

Comment: There are many questions about that, see `?scale_fill_manual`.